# tex4ht produces quotation marks instead of German umlauts

Tags: miktex, tex4ht, make4ht

A simple file with umlauts compiled using 
`make4ht test "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"`
shows question marks instead of German umlauts.
Here the MWE test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Files are encoded using UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %The text uses German umlauts
\begin{document}
A text with some „ÜÖÄüöäß“.
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
A text with some „�������“.
```

This seams to be a bug in the current MikTeX installation (is it a bug of tex4ht or MikTex?).

My current workaround was to copy the file `unicode.4hf`
from
`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\ht-fonts\unicode\charset`
to
`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\ht-fonts\unicode\charset\uni`
which solved the problem.

Comment: It might be Miktex issue, your code works for me in `TeXLive`. Note that you `make4ht -u test` is functionally equivalent to your command.

Comment: Imho it is the miktex bug you already found. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2350/

Comment: Michal, unfortunately usage of -u option with a more complex tex file and further tex4ht options such as "frames" leads to other problems (no output at all). I am currently trying to find out what the source of the problem is.

Comment: that would be clearly bug in `make4ht`, please try to make an example. there is actually one difference with `-u` option: it uses `-cmozhtf` instead of `-cunihtf`

Comment: Mihal, I am sorry, the -u option works well - I was using a wrong config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a problem with the current MikTeX distribution, see bug report and comments at https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2350/. The bug, which was originally reported by Ulrike Fischer and in the meantime has been marked as closed, still persists.

As mentioned there, the current workaround is copying the file `unicode.4hf` from `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\ht-fonts\unicode\charset` to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\ht-fonts\unicode` (or to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\ht-fonts\unicode\charset\uni`).

If using `make4ht` with the `-u` option (as suggested by Michal), make4ht calls tex4ht with `-cmozhtf` option. Then tex4ht is actually supposed to look for `unicode.4hf` in `ht-fonts/mozilla/charset/` directory but fails to find it there. In this case one should copy `unicode.4hf` from `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\ht-fonts\mozilla\charset` to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex4ht\ht-fonts\mozilla`.

Comment: could you please post output from `tex4ht` command? I mean lines below: `Make4ht: tex4ht  -cunihtf -utf8 "test.dvi"`. I am interested in location of `unicode.4hf` which is listed here

Comment: Sure:

    tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 Windows MiKTeX)
    tex4ht -cmozhtf 
      -utf8 
      test
    (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
    (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/charset/uni/unicode.4hf)
    (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.tfm)
    (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/ec/ec.htf)
    Searching ´lm-ec.htf' for ´ecrm1000.htf'
    (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-ec.htf)

Comment: ah, this is strange, it should be `ht-fonts/mozilla/charset/unicode.4hf` in your case, not `unicode/charset/uni/unicode.4hf`. It seems that `tex4ht` on `Miktex` can't find the correct file.

Comment: Yes. and as Ulrike mentioned in  https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2350/ without the workaround `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/iso8859/1/charset/uni/unicode.4hf)`is found instead.